# commuting a LU factorisation

Tags: numerical-linear-algebra

Consider the permutation matrix

$P=  \begin{pmatrix}
 0 & \cdots & 0 & 1 \\
  0 &  \cdots & 1 &0 \\
  \vdots  & \ddots  & \vdots & \vdots  \\
  1 & \cdots & 0 & 0 {}
 \end{pmatrix}$

SoI showed that if $L$ is lower triangular then $PLP$ is upper triangular.

Now the problem asks me to descrive how to calculate a factorisation $A=\overline U \ \overline L $

where $\overline U$ is unit upper triangular and $\overline L$ is lower triangular.

I am finding it difficult because I think the previous part was an hint to do the following:

$PAP=PLUP=PLP^2UP$
as $P^2=I$

And then simply define $\overline U = PLP$ and $\overline P = PUP$

How can I get rid of the $P$ s on the rhs?

Any hint would be appreciated, I think I am missing something!

Comment: actually, writing it down made it clearer to me.
is the way just considering the LU factorisation of the transpose of A?

Comment: If $A^T=LU$, then $A=U^TL^T$. $U^T$ is lower triangular and $L^T$ is upper triangular. It is a method to 'convert' between the Doolittle and Crout LU factorisations, if you want too.

Comment: ah yes, even easier, I think the question wasn't really clear! just to use P I'll do the same as what I wrote in the question substituting A by $A^{T}$ 
thank you!

Comment: Also, $PAP=A^T$. You may have already figured that out, though. :-)